# Сортировка словаря по ключу

Tags: python

Подскажите, как в Python можно отсортировать словарь по ключу? Сложность заключается в том, что ключи имеют строковый тип

**Исходный словарь:**

```
d = {'30': ['Математика'], '26': ['Русский язык'], '7': ['История'], '15': ['Музыка'], '33': ['География']}
```

**Должен получиться:**

```
d = {'7': ['История'], '15': ['Музыка'], '26': ['Русский язык'], '30': ['Математика'], '33': ['География']}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d = {'30': ['Математика'], '26': ['Русский язык'], '7': ['История'], '15': ['Музыка'], '33': ['География']}

sorted_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda f: int(f[0])))
print(sorted_d)
```

```
{'7': ['История'],
 '15': ['Музыка'],
 '26': ['Русский язык'],
 '30': ['Математика'],
 '33': ['География']}
```

Comment: @ Serhii Khortiuk спасибо. Могли бы объяснить, почему при написании d.items(), лямбда не ругается на слово dict_items([**кортежи**]). Почему лямбда функция пропускает это слово и просто сразу рассматривает список кортежей?

Comment: @Евгений key - это функция которая будет вызываться на каждом элементе для сравнения. `lambda f: int(f[0])` указывает что для сравнения будет использован первый элемент кортежа (наш ключ). Более подробно можете почитать [тут](https://tirinox.ru/sorted-key-param/)

Answer (score 2):

как вариант:

```
d = {'30': ['Математика'], '26': ['Русский язык'], '7': ['История'], '15': ['Музыка'], '33': ['География']}

d = {key: d[key] for key in sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda elem: int(elem))}

print(d)
```

Comment: `str(key)` не нужно, `key` не меняет ключи, в отсортированном словаре ключи останутся строками

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, опечатался